# How to upload a image to google drive using react native with react-native-drive-api-wrapper?

Tags: android, react-native, google-drive-api, multipartform-data, image-uploading

I am new to react native and using react-native-drive-api-wrapper to work with google drive in react native. So I am able to create folders and also able to create a new file with some content using this.

```
  const contents = "My text file contents";
  GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
       contents,
       "text/plain", {
         parents: ["root"],
         name: "text2.txt"
       },
       false);
```

But don't know how can I upload a file which there in my device to google drive. At the end my goal is to upload images and videos to drive. Please help me in going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to do image upload to google drive with base64, Here is the example code below.

```
fs.readFile("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190325_111404.jpg",'base64')
   .then((res => {             //conversion of image to base64
       console.log(res);
       GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
            res,
            "'image/jpg'", {
            parents: ["root"], //or any path
            name: "photo.jpg"
          },
            true)              //make it true because you are passing base64 string otherwise the uploaded file will be not supported
             .then(a=>{
            console.log(a);
          });
        }
        );
```

Comment: But in case of big file size, the android app crashes due to memory allocation error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)?

You can use it to get the image, then send the data to google drive.

Like

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
    if (response.uri) {
        // response.data is the actual image data.
        // response.type can give you the mime for pictures only
        // response.fileName for the name of the file.
        GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
            response.data,
            response.type, {
                parents: ["root"],
                name: response.fileName,
            }, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: What actually the respone.data and type should contain. can you please place some example line there istead of comment

Comment: response.data is the base64 encoded image data (photos only). and response.type is the mime of the image... You can check [react-native-image-picker documentation for full api referrence](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md)